# Minimum Numbers of Cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the minimum number of Cards to be dealt from an arbitrarily shuffled deck of 52 cards to guarantee that three cards are from the same suit ?

Comment: 9 is the Ans ..But I want to know, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four suits in total, so in the worst possible scenario you are dealt four cards, all of different suit, then again you are dealt four cards, all of different suit, but now whichever card you are dealt will be the same suit as two of the cards you already have.
So you only need to be dealt 9 cards.

EDIT: you are asked the minimum number of cards to be  **absolutely** certain that you have 3 cards of the same suit.
Now, this means that you have to think about the worst case scenario. Now, I will assume you are dealt the cards one by one.
I will call the 4 suits C (clubs), D (diamonds), H (hearts) and S (spades).
Suppose you are dealt less than 9 cards, say only 8, and they are the following suits (listed in the order they were dealt): C,D,H,S,C,D,H,S. So with only 8 cards, you might not be dealt three cards of the same suit.
Now try to add a new card to the sequence above (to C,D,H,S,C,D,H,S). What do you get?

Comment: You ans. is correct,May you please elaborate it a little ?

Comment: Ok, which bit don't you understand?

Comment: embarrassingly almost all of them :-( Please explain taking an example

Comment: OK, I edit the answer!

Comment: Ok I got that. Qus : why i didn't go for best case scenario , I mean First three cards can be from the same suit ,why not?

Comment: But you cannot choose which cards you are dealt. Suppose you are dealt only 3 cards (you cannot choose or see them!), how can you be sure they are the same suit? In fact, would you bet they are the same suit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10601/discussion-between-user2509211-and-dado)

Answer (score 0):

Deal 2 cards from each suit + one more card. And then it's sure that 3 will be from the same suit.

Comment: That's correct (4*(2)+1)=9 .Thanks!